# Error in reading an xml from google news Warning: file_get_contents

Tags: php, xml, stream

I need to read an xml,I dont find another way to read it just this, I just harcoded the $movie and this and I get this error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://news.google.com.mx/news?hl=es&gl=mx&q=harry potter&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

I get this error and this is my code, the error is in the url can someone help, how to fix it???

```
$url = 
$data = file_get_contents('http://news.google.com.mx/news?hl=es&gl=mx&q='.$movie.'&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$channel = array();
$channel['title'] = $xml->channel->title;

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{

    //echo $article['title'] = $item->title;
    //echo $article['link'] = $item->link;
    echo $article['pubDate'] = $item->pubDate;
    echo $article['description'] = (string) trim($item->description);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) the URL parameters (i.e. `$movie`), it should work as expected.

Example:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://news.google.com.mx/news?hl=es&gl=mx&q='. urlencode($movie) .'&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss')
```

Comment: I tried this: $data = file_get_contents(urlencode('http://news.google.com.mx/news?hl=es&gl=mx&q='.$cine.'&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss')); and i get failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: Just `$movie` or any other parameter passed in the query string (after `?`) that may contain special characters or spaces.

Comment: @brettz9 You are right, thanks, I removed that note from the answer.

Comment: It works, but it is already safe for encoding. Basically you just need to escape unknown input which is not already escaped. But if it is known to be safe, you don't need to escape (e.g., if you were always going to use Harry Potter, you could just hard-code it in the URL as "harry+potter"). Encoding is needed with Harry Potter (or unknown text) because spaces need escaping.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the `$movie` in urlencode. I've also added a content-type header so you can specify the UTF-8 encoding used in that feed and render the text properly for non-English characters.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');

$movie = 'harry potter';
$url = 
$data = file_get_contents('http://news.google.com.mx/news?hl=es&gl=mx&q='.urlencode($movie).'&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$channel = array();
$channel['title'] = $xml->channel->title;

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
    //echo $article['title'] = $item->title;
    //echo $article['link'] = $item->link;
    echo $article['pubDate'] = $item->pubDate;
    echo $article['description'] = (string) trim($item->description);
}

?>
```